# Redirect subdomain into top-level domain's folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

Here's what I'm trying to do.

When you type **m.example.com** I want users to be redirected to **example.com/m/** but I would like the url in the address bar to remain m.example.com if possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that with mod_rewrite and mod_proxy:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/m%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

Comment: @JackSpairow Use `R=301` instead of `P`.

Comment: are there any specific settings needed in mod_proxy for this?

Comment: Is there a way to do this even if the subdomain **m.example.com** does not exist.

Comment: @GovindBalaji The domain must be handled successfully by the DNS to point to the right IP address and must be accepted/mapped by the web server.

Comment: @Gumbo in my web host, no of subdomains is limited. Can I use htaccess to overcome this?

Comment: @GovindBalaji In that case probably not because your server won’t accept arbitrary virtual host names.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the subdomain's root dir to example.com/m/. Then there is no redirection.