# subdomain redirection in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, redirect

I was wondering if the following scenario is possible using htaccess rules.
I want one subdomain to be redirected to another url.
I have contact the server admin to add the "test" subdomain to "example.com" domain.
The main domain has no other subdomains.

What rule must i put in htaccess to do achieve:
http://test.example.com to be redirected to http://www.something-else.com.

NOTE: www.something-else.com is a complicated url (200 chars length)

**EDIT**
My full htaccess file now looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/redir.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The htaccess file is located to example.com root directory.
I have no physical access to test subdirectory, although i know it exists - ping to that url shows me the IP of example.com

Typing test.example.com to the browser's address bar has no effect. White screen, no redirection, no nothing. If some page exists there, i know not.

Comment: @Book Of Zeus : https://www.somdomain.com/a/folder1/somepage?var=xxx&var2=xxx&var3=xxx&var4=http://another-domain.com/folder1/xxxxx/&var5=xxx&var6=xxxx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1460652/567986 but you should remove the `,P` at the end and remove %{REQUEST_URI}.

Comment: i tried the rule and it works for me (using my site of course) now can you please provide more info about the `has no effect. White screen, no redirection, no nothing`, like can you share a httpfox of this? maybe the subdomain is not set properly or something

Comment: @Book Of Zeus when i type the subdomain address in browser, it shows me a white screen. It seems like there is a page, but no content.
If i try to visit test.example.com/index.htm i get a not found error. The url remains the same (test.example.com)

Comment: what the log say? what's in the test.example.com folder (any .htaccess?)?

Comment: @Book Of Zeus hmmmm... i have no ftp access to test subdomain. I try to make it work from the main domain (example.com)

Comment: @Book Of Zeus yes i got ftp access anduploaded my htaccess there. it works like a charm.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For static urls:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.somdomain.com/a/folder1/somepage?var=xxx&var2=xxx&var3=xxx&var4=http://another-domain.com/folder1/xxxxx/?&var5=xxx&var6=xxxx [R=301,NC,L]
```

For Dynamic urls (if the original domain has folders that needs to be moved to the other domain):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.somdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

*From your edit:*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redir.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: no it doenst work. At first glance i thought that the redirection url was breaking the htaccess. I put it in a php file and change my htaccess to redirect the subdomain to the php file. Still not working.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/redir.php [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: Still nothing. It should work, i know, but it doesn't. I have edited my original post to show my full htaccess. I am confused. It seemed so simple at first