# Rewrite url for multiple subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite url to for two subdomains in .htaccess

`domain1.test.com` -> `domain1.test.com/test1`

`domain2.test.com` ->  `domain2.test.com/test2`.

Whats the proper to achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subdomain redirection in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383284/subdomain-redirection-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.test.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test1/$1 [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.test.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test2/$1 [NC,L]
```