# Redirect all to index.php using htaccess with subdomain

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I would like to set up an htaccess file that routes requests for any subdomain to the index.php file in the /public_html/ folder.

For example, I want

> mydomain.com/index.html -> mydomain.com/index.php

and

> app.mydomain.com/loginForm -> mydomain.com/index.php

I tried this way, but when I have link with app subdomain, I have 404

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [subdomain redirection in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383284/subdomain-redirection-in-htaccess)

Comment: @Patrick I think this may be a little more complicated as the default file type on hosting for index.* may be .html which will also need to be changed.

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester Not nessesary. What the hosting defaults to is usually many different file types, where the order is preference, example: DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm . That would then depend on the setup of the Directory Index