# Domain rewrites to a folder

Tags: .htaccess

I am fairly new to the whole .htaccess thing but I have a question. I would like to set up a system so that every thing typed before the domain rewrites to a folder on the website. To make it more clear this is an example:

if the user types for example:

```
example1.example.com
```

it has to get the site form the root /example1/ folder.

if the user types for example:

```
klsdjf.example.com
```

it has to get the site form the root /klsdjf/ folder.

I hope this is a clear explanation of what I want to achieve.

Thanx,

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456956/redirect-subdomain-to-folder

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but when I impllement this it gives me this error: Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you'd like a rewrite rule from a wildcard subdomain to be routed to a root folder.

so,

```
*.example.com => example.com/*
```

**Step 1. Configure your DNS**

First, you have to make sure that your DNS host is configured correctly. You have to make sure that your domain accepts a wildcard (*) that points to the IP address of your host. This should be a simple A record.

**Step 2. Tell Apache to Treat Subdomains Differently**

After that is done, you have to tell Apache to treat subdomains differently.

In httpd.conf, look for something that looks like this:

```
ServerAlias www.example.com example.com
```

And change it to this:

```
ServerAlias www.example.com example.com *.example.com
```

example.com, of course, being the name of your website.

**Step 3. Actual Rewriting Rules**

Then, here is your .htaccess:

```
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).example.com [NC]
   RewriteRule (.*) %2/$1 [L]
```

That should work.