# Folder to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

My server provider stopped give me possible way to create subdomains in control panel and they say I should solve it with htaccess.

So I have to do something like this. When user types http://asdf.example.com it should get the content of http://example.com/asdf (as the provider changed even the FTP's structure... how kind of them)

I don't find any tutorial for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect subdomain to folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456956/redirect-subdomain-to-folder)

Answer (score 2):

More generic version of TerryE's answer. I haven't tested it though!!!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).example.com
RewriteCond %1/$0        !^([^/]+)/\1
RewriteRule ^.*          %1/$0   [L]
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because on the first pass fred.ex... cond1 will set %1 as `fred` for cond2, but the regexp for cond2 will fail, so even though the cond succeeds (because of the ! operator), %1 won't be set for the rewrite rule.  *However*, we should be able to split rule rule pattern `^([^/|+/)?(.*)` and set $1 and $2 then use `RewriteCond $1%1 !^(.*?)/\1` as the no equal check followed by a repeat of cond2 to reset %1.  Still +1 'cos its a good idea.  Back to my Greek Island retreat !!

Comment: There was a small typo; `|` should have been `]`.

Comment: @TerryE I used to think that too, but as far as I know the ! will also disable back-references for that condition, %1 will still contain the subdomain. I testing the code above on my own server, and it seems to work okay.

Comment: Hummnn, just rechecked the docs "These are backreferences of the form **%N** (1 <= N <= 9), which provide access to the grouped parts (again, in parentheses) of the pattern, from the last matched `RewriteCond` in the current set of conditions." so you are correct.  The match fails, but the cond succeeds due to the **!** operator and %1 is passed through from the previous cond. If the experts get surprised then I pity the novices :LoL:

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with mod_rewrite and mod_proxy:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^asdf\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/asdf%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need mod proxy.  Just do an internal redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} =asdf.example.com
RewriteCond   $0           !^asdf/
RewriteRule   ^.*          asdf/$0             [L]
```

The rule rewrite the request prefixing `asdf/` but only if (1) the host is `http:/asdf...` and (2) the rewrite hasn't already taken place.  You need (2) to prevent iterative loops.  $0 is the match string in the rule.

Hope this helps.